# Repetition of gradle properties error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have started a new project on android studio 2 new version. then "Error:Unable to start the daemon process." these line shows up.
Then i change my Gradle properties by adding this line

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

But when i started a new project this lines shows up again:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at 
https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

How can i permanently setup the Gradle properties to avoid this every time.

Comment: How many RAM do you have? Do you use gradle-wrapper or local distribution?

Comment: I have 32 GB of RAM (~16 GB free right now..) -- none of the solutions below worked, but at least this did. -- even if it's painful and it would be nice if there was another way, at least the one provided in the question works for now. 

Answer (score -1):

Open the file located at `androidStudio/bin/studio.vmoptions`

it should look like this, if not change it accordingly

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
.......
```

This will most probably solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

This message suggests `gradle` still don't have enough memory space. If you have 4GB RAM or more, try to increase it in `gradle.properties` , e.g:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

If error still occurs, try to delete `.gradle` directory (C:\Users\your_username\.gradle), then invalidate cache and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Could you show content of `gradle.properties` and `studio.exe.vmoptions`?